# UITableViewCell background color is different in iOS5 vs iOS4

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, ios5

The grouped `UITableViewCell` uses `tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor` color instead of regular `whiteColor` color, in iOS 5. As a result, the background of your custom cells doesn't match with those of `UITableViewCell` (Default, Subtitle, Value1, Value2 style cells).

What's the best way to make sure that same background color is used in custom `UITableViewCell` and default `UITableViewCell` (and associated `UILabel` and other elements) - w.r.t. both iOS4 and iOS5?

Note: In the Editor i can see a new color by the name of `tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor`, but there's no category/method available to get this color programmatically.

**Edit:**

You can use following technique to change the background color of controls on your cell, but in-case of custom cells, how can you set appropriate background color based on the OS (iOS 4 vs iOS 5)?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        view.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

**Easiest solution (my current implemented):**
This just makes sure that all my cells have white background, irrespective of the OS. Somehow, i don't need to apply white color to `cell.contentView.subviews`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one quick-and-dirty way to do it, presuming we're dealing with a solid background color, no gradients or anything like that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        subview.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

On iOS 5, it can help avoid unsightly view lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could set the backgroundColor of your subviews (labels etc) to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: This is not good idea cos setting transparent color for the background on any view slow down performance. If you dont need gradient background than you should set background to opaque. That's what Apple recommends and that's also my experience...

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass `UITableViewCell` you could also try overriding `setBackgroundColor`:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    [[self myLabel] setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

It appears that this method is used by iOS when it sets the default background colour for the cell.